# Standart Retiming circuit with two D type Flip Flops

Tags: logic-gates, clock, flipflop, timing, synchronous

I am trying to build a button(for adjusting the clock) syncroniser circuit for a seven segment clock. The button signals are of course async inputs so there needs to be retiming to make sure it goes through once as the press will take more than one clock cycle.

I have to use 2 dtypes for retiming it but other then serially conecting them I can't find a way to create the ircuit. What would be considered a "standart retiming circuit with 2 flip flops?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by your phrase so I can't offer any help in re-phrasing it to what you want. You have something in your head that you may need to communicate better. Maybe someone else gets it. My only guess is that you want fast up/down buttons so you can rapidly adjust the time on a 7-seg clock. But if so, all I can say is that I'm guessing only based upon this being a clock and barely at all upon what you wrote. Can you talk more about what you have in hand (schematic reference, for example) and write more about what you hope to achieve?

Comment: Is this your design of clock, or a purchased module? Who says the button 'needs' thisd treatment you hint at? What happens if you use a simple button on that input?

Comment: This is mostly a part of a project that I have to fit the circuit to the specification, the clock is not a purchased module. The description is very close to the spec. Essentially I am trying to get one clock cycle worth of signal out of a button press. These buttons are used to adjust a 7 segment 3digit clock. They output signals to the main sequencer which is not yet designed.